# What benefits gives image switcher?

Tags: android

I searched for ways to display images and found next [exampple](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/image-gallery-example-in-android/). I wonder why imageswitcher was used over imageview?  Does it give any specific benefits?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

    <ImageSwitcher android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

    <Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:background="#55000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:spacing="16dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

public class ImageGalleryExample extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
        mSwitcher.setFactory(this);
        mSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));
        mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));

        Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        g.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        mSwitcher.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    public View makeView() {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
        i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return i;
    }

    private ImageSwitcher mSwitcher;

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

            i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture_frame);
            return i;
        }

        private Context mContext;

    }

    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_thumb_0, R.drawable.sample_thumb_1,
            R.drawable.sample_thumb_2, R.drawable.sample_thumb_3};

    private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2,
            R.drawable.sample_3};

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I wonder why imageswitcher was used over imageview?` ? Please brief your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of benefits if you want a sliding display of multiple images.

It gives you:

- Scale images to fit screen
- Easy animation control while sliding
- View recycling to save memory

If you think you can do better than that, you can always do the whole implementation yourself. But that would take much effort which is not very necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> Sometimes you don't want an image to appear abruptly on the screen,
>   rather you want to apply some kind of animation to the image when it
>   transitions from one image to another. This is supported by android in
>   the form of ImageSwitcher.

[More Details With Sample](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_imageswitcher.htm)